# How to pass Typeface through bundle?

Tags: android, fonts, bundle, typeface

I'm wondering how to put typeface through bundle ?

It seems typeface isn't parcelable or serializable so it can't be put in bundle.

I've found the tips of pass the typeface's hashcode with `putInt()` and `getInt()` but I don't know if it's a clean code.

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you for your help

**EDIT:**

Here are some details to understand what I search to do :

I've two fragment :

1. In the first I've an EditText with a Typeface that I can change.
2. In the second, I've a recyclerView with a list of Typeface.

My purpose is to get the typeface of the EditText from the 1st fragment in the 2nd fragment, to highlight the correct Typeface in the list.

I succeeded to do this by sending the hashcode of the typeface. But I'm not feeling that is a good practice.

Comment: Have you tried to pass it as Serializeable?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? If you're trying to pass it within your app, you shouldn't need to do that. If you're trying to pass it to another app, you just can't do that.

Comment: @AntonisRadz Yes I've tried that and Typeface isn't serializable

Comment: @MikeM. I'm trying to pass the current typeface of an editText between two fragment

Comment: The answer below has the right idea. Track your `Typeface`s by name instead. Though the hash code idea might work on newer versions, with a smallish number of different `Typeface`s (up to 16, I believe), it is possible that creating two of the same one will end up with different objects. Also, on older versions, not all `Typeface`s were cached, so it's even more likely then.

Comment: Thank you for your explain, I suspected that hashcode isn't a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first fragment where the edittext is present, put

String selectedEditTextFont =  "Roboto-Medium.ttf";

mEditText.setFont(selectedEditTextFont);

```
public class ForexTextView extends AppCompatEditText { 

    public void setFont(String fontName) {
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
        setTypeface(myTypeface);
    }
}
```

Now, selectedEditTextFont string has the final selectedFont value. You need to pass it through bundle.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("SelectedFont", selectedEditTextFont);
 Fragment fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
```

In the second fragment where the recyclerview is located you need to check with this selectedEditTextFont like this in **adapter** class.

```
if(selectedEditTextFont.equals(arrRecyclerViewRow.get(ADAPTER_POSITION_HERE).getFontType){
//To highlight particular row
lLaylist.setBackGroundColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.yellow));
}
```

You need to make setFontType with associated list and need to put it into model class. So you can getFontType() in adapter class.

Comment: Thank you, now I find my font by name instead of hashcode. I've adapted your answer to my case and it works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

I think you pass in a bundle with a font name am I right?

please try the pass name of the font and get font name and set.

```
Intent intent=new Intent (..,..);
intent.putString("fontname","abc.ttf");
 startActivity(inent);
```

Comment: I search to send the current typeface of an EditText between two fragments. In the second fragment I've a list of TypeFace, and I have to find wich Typeface matchs with the sended one.